# SQL Server 2008 DATETIME column data type does not default to current date with getdate()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL 2008, I have a table that I created where I have 2 NOT NULL columns.  ID which is an identity column and a DATETIME column which is a datetime datatype and in the default value or binding I've set it to getdate() but I'm getting the error below when executing the following SP. Any suggestions/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

When I execute the following SP I get the error below:

```
USE [MachoPOSt]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sbssp_InsertTblArchivedMessages]    Script Date: 03/08/2013 

14:16:20 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sbssp_InsertTblArchivedMessages]
(
      @xmlString varchar(max),
      @fromToMach bit
)
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      DECLARE @idoc int, @lastId int
      EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @xmlString

      INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblArchivedMessages]
      SELECT * 
      FROM OPENXML(@idoc, '/ATM', 2) WITH [dbo].[tblArchivedMessages]

      EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc

      SET @lastId = (SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('tblArchivedMessages'))

      UPDATE [dbo].[tblArchivedMessages] 
        SET FromToMach = @fromToMach 
        WHERE ID = @lastId
END
```

Here is the ERROR:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure
>   sbssp_InsertTblArchivedMessages, Line 14 Cannot insert
>   the value NULL into column 'DateTime', table
>   'MachoPOSt.dbo.tblArchivedMessages'; column does not
>   allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: It's too long.  I've got 131 columns. Here are the 2 columns that are NOT NULL:
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[DateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [DF_tblArchivedMessages_TimeStamp]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [DateTime]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an explicit column list that excludes the `datetime` column.

The `default` only takes effect if you don't supply a value at all or use the `default` keyword. You must be inserting `NULL` from that error message.

So your query would be something like

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblArchivedMessages]
            (col1,
             col2)
SELECT col1,
       col2
FROM   OPENXML(@idoc, '/ATM', 2) WITH [dbo].[tblArchivedMessages]
```

Comment: I'm actually NOT using the identity or datetime column now and the other columns come from the XML that I'm passing in. I have 3 columns that are NOT in the XML.  2 are NOT NULL and have a default of identity and datetime with getdate() as default value and the third I'm updating AFTER the insert.  Why would I need to explicitly identify each column? I have 131 columns and hope not to list everyone in a INSERT STATEMENT.  Thanks.

Comment: @Melinda - If you do an `INSERT` without a column list it **is** including the `datetime` column. The only columns that are automatically ignored are `IDENTITY`, `TIMESTAMP` and computed columns. If you want to ignore other columns you need an explicit column list, Or the only other thing you can do is create a view which has the 130 desired columns in it (missing the `datetime` one) and insert into that.

Comment: Understood. Sorry to be so thick.  I'll try that.  Appreciate your response and help.  Regards.

Comment: Martin - another question if you don't mind. When I did as you indicated above and not explicitly define the 2 columns that are IDENTITY or TIMESTAMP, I included the 1 column that was a NOT NULL column.  
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblArchivedMessages]
(FromToMach) 
SELECT @fromToMach 
FROM OPENXML(@idoc, '/ATM', 2) WITH [dbo].[tblArchivedMessages]
And now all the columns that get populated by XML are NULL. I tried adding all 128 columns but got error that I had too many column in insert stmt than my SELECT.  I apparently did something wrong. Any help/direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin already said, you will have to specify all columns. To make the typing a little easier, you can use drag&drop in SSMS:

1. Connect Object Explorer to your server.
2. find the database and table
3. under the table find the column folder
4. drag the entire folder into an open query window

This will automatically insert the complete comma separated list of all columns. After that you just have to delete the two you don't need.

Comment: So in the FROM OPENXML statement, you're saying I need to identify each of the 128 columns. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the only column list required in your case is the list of columns to insert into: `INSERT INTO dbo.Tbl(col1,col2) SELECT * FROM <...>`. However, it is in general better to always specify all columns and avoid `SELECT *`. This will make your code more stable and more maintainable. As we spend 80% of our time maintaining existing code and only 20% writing new code it is well worth that little extra effort.